# Problem with table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I have an urgent problem to be fixed :(

In my thesis, there is a requirement to add the approval page to the table of content.

I have already an approval page as a separate "approvalPage.tex" file, and I add this to my thesis (thesis.tex) after \begin{document} as below:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}APPROVAL PAGE}
\input{approvalPage}
\clearpage
```

Then, when I check the ToC part in compiled pdf, I see something like below:

[image]

As you can the "APPROVAL PAGE" is aligned with chapters and it is positioned right.

Would you please help me to fix this? I need this part to be aligned with the other parts like abstract, acknowledgements etc.

Best wishes,

Answer (score 1):

Using `\numberline` is for numbered entries. For an unnumbered chapter you want:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPROVAL PAGE}
\input{approvalPage}
\clearpage
```

Comment: Thanks for your help